# Subscribe doesn't work with Knockout Model as function

Tags: knockout.js

I think I'm struggling with the basics here.
The code:

```
var VehicleSearchViewModel = function() {

  this.VehicleVariantId = ko.observable(0);

  this.VehicleVariantId.subscribe(function (id) {
      console.log(id);
  });
};
```

from the function **outside** of this, I do the following:

```
VehicleSearchViewModel.VehicleVariantId = 777;
```

...and `console.log` **doesn't fire**. Albeit if I type `VehicleSearchViewModel.VehicleVariantId` in the console I can see it's been updated with the new value. What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: where are you actually binding this?  I suspect you're missing a `new` keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout [observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) are **functions**. You need to set them by passing the new value as a parameter.

`VehicleSearchViewModel.VehicleVariantId(777);`

You really should go through [the tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), you are going to have a lot of questions that can be answered by them.

Comment: in your fiddle `reset` function needs to be called from another JavaScript class to replicate my requirement

Comment: Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/X7ZuY/2/)? If not, please make a fiddle demonstrating your issue, its not clear.

Comment: hi, it was more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/X7ZuY/13/ but it works. the problem was I wasn't using the `instance` of a viewModel like you are.